# Unable to update data in real time firebase databse

Tags: python, flask, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I am making a web app using flask and for using firebase int he backend I am using pyrebase. I have created a user account, sent the profile data in the form of json object and saved to real-time database. The structure if data is like this;
[image: database before update]

Now I want to update values of income and expenses. I am updating the income data like this;

```
        income = request.form.get("income")
        price = request.form.get("price")
        data = {"income" : income, "price": price}
        incomes.append(data)
        a = db.child("users").update({"incomes": incomes})
```

But the income value is not getting updated in the firebase. Instead it is getting added like this;
[image: after update]

How to update the value. I looked for readme of pyrebase and followed the same method for updating value.

Comment: Yes I tried yuor solution and it worked fine. But I could not make it generic to fetch each user. You said `So in your case you need to know the -Mh2v8... key too and pass that into your update call:` API responds with idToken, refresh token email and a few other entities but I did not find any information about this specific key assigned to each user. I do not know how to fetch it.

Comment: Are you asking how to find a node in the database with the given email? That'd be a new, separate question, but would start with https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#complex-queries

Answer (score 0):

To write a value to a node to the Realtime Database you need to know the exact path of that node. So in your case you need to know the `-Mh2v8...` key too and pass that into your update call:

```
db.child("users").child("-Mh2v89LOLthJBSImbN-").update({"incomes": incomes})
```

If you initially *read* the data from the database, it is easiest to remember the key of each item at that moment.

If you really don't know the key, but know some other unique property of the user, you can [use a query](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#complex-queries) to look up the user's key based on that unique value.